# Embed video from facebook on mobile website dosen't showen

Tags: facebook, flash, mobile, video, embed

I have tried to embed a facebook video on my website, but on the mobile phones it doesn't appear.

For example:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151630731455498

They give me the embed code from the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151630731455498" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And on the mobile website it requires flash player, the problem is that iOS machines don't have this option.

Is there any other solution for embedding videos from facebook into my mobile website?

Thanks.